# HashSet implementations

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

As per the HashSet.java, the internal design of the HashSet uses HashMap

```
 public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

the java doc says

> This class implements the `Set` interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a `HashMap` instance).

Most of the books refer HashSet as  **"it is implemented by a hash table"** by Java Generics

What is the reason for the strech of the HashTable ? Why not HashMap ?

Comment: "hash table` is not referring to the `HashTable` class.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is an abstract data structure that can be implemented in many different ways. In the Java standard library, `HashMap` is one such implementation, and `HashTable` is another. The wording in the documentation refers to hash tables in the generic.

Answer (score 0):

What they are trying to explain is that HashMap is a Java implementation of a general structure - the hash table. And that it implements the Set interface, which means that every entry is guaranteed to be unique